# why is my displacement map not sharp?

Tags: animation, edges, nurbs-surface, displacement

[image][image: text engraving]

The displacement map is an animation of the letters being engraved in the metal. The animation itself works just fine. The only problem is the edges of the letters. How can i get them straight instead of this?

-I tried a higher amount of subdivisions but that doesn't seem to work (blender crashes). 
-I am also pretty sure it has got nothing to do with the animation i made in after effects.

Comment: Do you have **Displacement modifier** on top of your modifiers stack?

Comment: Increase the subdivisions and also check if their value for "Render View" is set at least to the same amount than it is in 3D view.

Comment: @PaulGonet , I only have 1 modifier and that's the displace modifier.

Comment: @metaphor_set, If I try to open the subdivisions 'tab' ( by going into edit mode> 'w' > subdivide) blender crashes. I think the last image I uploaded explains why.

Comment: Instead of a "normal" subdivide I'd always go with a Subdivision Modifier or a Multiresolution Modifier. They won't change how subdivision works but at least they are non-distructive as long as you don't apply them. Nice clean letters could also be done by importing them as curves and using the extrusion method. It's a little more work but the result is much better imho.

Comment: What's the resolution of your displacement image? A low resolution map could be causing that too.
Try again with another copy of the image saved in very high resolution (and preferrably in 16bpc with a pinch of blur to produce glentler edges.

Comment: @Gez , Thanks that could be it, I'll check it out!

Comment: I would suggest download the latest Blender build https://builder.blender.org/download/ (2.78)  and use the new microdisplacements feature. I tried this with creating a gold seal and it looks very good with not much work. I would watch this tutorial to understand it better. http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-microdisplacements/